# Is there any word that varies in length when written in hanja or hangul?

Tags: hangul, hanja, orthography

I've learned that due to Korean syllable structure, every hanja is exactly one hangul block long. Is there any Sino-Korean word (한자어) that deviates from this rule (by colloquial sound change etc.) that could be longer or shorter when written in hangul, or no exception at all?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TL;DR version:** While Japanese *kanji* can be be represented by any number of syllables, Korean *hanja* always represents a single syllable. Korean words of Chinese origin that have had some sound changes applied are not interchangeable with *hanja* except in rare cases.

---

Some words are Chinese in origin but have been nativized through sound changes. Take this common verb for example:

---

**괜찮다** comes from the longer expression **공연하지아니하다** with **공연** coming from the *hanja* **空然**. It probably came to be through common use. The expression became weathered down by the lashing of human tongues over the centuries.

The pronunciation of **공연** merged together to become **괜**. While it’s obvious that the **ㄱ**, **ㅗ**, and **ㄴ** were carried over, less obvious are the processes behind the disappearance of the final **ㅇ** and transformation of **ㅕ** into **ㅐ**. I can explain the former quite easily, but the latter is my own guess based on my knowledge of Korean phonology:

1. The **/ŋ/** sound (ㅇ) in the coda position is susceptible to weakening in many languages. In fact, this is apparent in Chinese borrowings into Japanese. In words where most modern Chinese varieties have **/ŋ/**, Japanese has a long vowel. **空** is /kɯː/ in Japanese, but /ko**ŋ**/ in Korean and Mandarin. Most telling though, is that the null initial and /ŋ/ are both written with the same letter! They were originally written as **ㅇ** and **ㆁ** respectively, but still the graphical similarity is no coincidence. Other letters based on the circle shape are **ㆆ** and **ㅎ**, with the former being deleted in most cases as in **일** (one) which had been written with the sequence **ㆆㅣᇙ**.
2. The **ㅗ** can only combine with a limited number of following vowels because of vowel harmony: **ㅣ** and **ㅏ**. And because **ㅣ** can only be at the beginning or end of a diphthong/triphthong, the iotized vowels (ㅑ, ㅕ, ㅛ, and ㅠ) cannot follow **ㅗ**. I believe, the **ㅕ** first underwent progressive metaphony to become **ㅑ** before metathesizing to **ㅐ**. Of course, **궨** might have also been an equally possible outcome but the **ㅏ** in the following syllable might have had an influence.

**하지아니하** became **찮** through the following mergers:

- **하지** became **ㅊ** (ㅎ+ㅈ=ㅊ)

  - The **ㅏ** was elided.
  - The **ㅈ**—being a palatal consonant—absorbed the **ㅣ**—a “palatal” vowel. In modern Korean transliterations of foreign words that end in a palatal sibilant-like sound, Korean employs **ㅣ** as an epenthetic vowel. “Image” is transliterated as “이미지” since **ㅣ** produces the least audible sound after **ㅈ**. Chinese and Japanese borrow such words in a similar manner.
- **아** was preserved as **ㅏ**.
- **니** became **ㄴ**.
- **하** became **ㅎ**.

---

Another word in Korean that has Chinese origins is **빗** (comb). This was borrowed from Old Chinese **篦** back when it was still pronounced something like /pis/. Today, the sounds have changed in both languages with /pis/ becoming /pit/ in Korean and /pi/ (Pinyin: bì) in Mandarin Chinese. And the *hangul* for **篦** is **비**. **빗** does not have a *hanja* representation even though its *hanja* origin is clear.

---

And now, to *really* answer the question: words like **괜찮다** are never written with *hanja* even in mixed-script mode. The fact that they had origins in *hanja* is usually left as footnotes in a dictionary. So without exception, the one-to-one rule stands.

**Sources:** [NAVER Korean Dictionary](http://m.krdic.naver.com/entry/3858300/) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EB%B9%97)

(Other such examples likely exist. It is even a phenomenon in some Chinese dialects!)

Answer (score 7):

Every hanja is exactly one syllable, no exceptions. No sound change made hanja pronunciation vary in syllable length since when hanja came to Korea (which was a looong time ago).

Answer (score 1):

Korean is [phonogram](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/phonogram):

> a unit symbol of a phonetic writing system, standing for a speech
>   sound, syllable, or other sequence of speech sounds without reference
>   to meaning.

While Chinese is [ideogram](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ideogram?s=t):

> a written symbol that represents an idea or object directly rather
>   than a particular word or speech sound, as a Chinese character.

There is no Chinese character that cannot be pronounced using one Hangul block and the Korean pronunciation of Chinese characters is different from [pinyin](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pinyin?s=t).

[Dictionary.com]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the Chinese language isn't involved in my question. What I wanted to ask is whether something like, for example, the English word spelled as _colonel_ and read like _kernel_, exists. In this case, syllable counts based on spelling and pronunciation doesn't match up.

Comment: @broccoliforest There is no such case as Korean is phonogram. It writes as it sounds.

Comment: I wonder, are there no historical/regional linguistic changes where the original monosyllable pronunciation of a specific hanja has evolved into a polysyllabic pronunciation (still written as one hanja)? Or the inverse, that a two-syllable word (written with two hanja) has evolved into a one-syllable word (still written as two hanja)? I cannot believe that a living language have _not_ evolved these “exceptions”.

Comment: @KessVargavind The Korean alphabet 한글 was invented on Oct. 9, 1446 and the Chinese characters have been around for thousands of years. The primary reason to invent the alphabet was to teach the common people to read, write and express themselves as Chinese characters were too complicated and only learned by the noble people. There has been no enough time for those *exceptions* to occur.

Comment: @Rathony, I am aware of the (basic) history of Hangul, but in my experience (former linguistics major) five hundred years is a lot of time for such exceptions occur! I will have to put this on my list of things to look up.

Comment: @KessVargavind Even though it was invented in the 15th century, it got popular among commoners only in the 19th century. You are overthingking this.

Comment: @Rathony, with a quick search I found this article by Jae-kee Shim from 1995, at least related to what I’m asking: [Hidden compound words in Korean](http://s-space.snu.ac.kr/handle/10371/63580) (will look it up further when I have more time on my hands).

Comment: @KessVargavind Those examples are compound words where Chinese characters and original Korean characters are combined to form a new word. It has nothing to do with the OP's question.

Comment: @Rathony As far as I know, only a small subset of Chinese characters can be considered ideograms.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Yes, you are right. The characters started as ideogram. But how many things can you describe using the characters. The number is limited. Also, you need to note that the other Chinese characters are not phonogram, either. I would rather call it half or one third phonogram.

Comment: I should have added that John DeFrancis considered Chinese as a [morphosyllabic system](http://www.pinyin.info/readings/texts/visible/index.html), a term/category that he invented.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Well, the link is too long for me to read now. Anyway, whatever you call it, Chinese is not phonogram. It can never be.

Comment: @KessVargavind On Wiktionary/Wikipedia I found these 2 pages: “窟窿” (Wiktionary) and “Jin Chinese” (Wikipedia). The article on Jin Chinese claims that many formerly monosyllabic words were split into disyllables. Unfortunately, there are no sources cited in the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there is a one to one correspondence between hanja to hangul.
i.e. Hangul (sound) whereas hanja the (Chinese character).

Comment: Hi user715 and welcome to the site. You can change your name to 'Simon' in your profile :  http://korean.stackexchange.com/users/edit/715

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about Chinese, yet in Chinese there are a few "ligature characters" that are used as a shorthand for certain words; for example 圕 for 圖書館 túshūguǎn "library", 瓩 for 千瓦 qiānwǎ "kilowatt", 浬 for 海里 hǎilǐ "nautical mile", 哩 for 英里 yīnglǐ "(English) mile", etc. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:CJK_ligatures and its three subcategories have some other ligature characters that don't seem to be in Unicode.

Also, unless in formal style, the rare numerals 廿 niàn "20", 卅 sà "30", 卌 xì "40", 皕 bì "200" are usually pronounced as if they were written 二十 èrshí, 三十 sānshí, 四十 sìshí, and 二百/两百 èrbǎi/liǎngbǎi.

I don't have a super-large Korean dictionary, but it is conceivable that at least one of these characters is (or was) also used in Korean and read using more than one syllable. Perhaps someone here might want to check.